# Side effects mutable.Map scala

Tags: scala, side-effects

When I try to insert an element in mutable `Map`, I expected that this element was insert in my Map and not in return Map ( like PF, immutable obj ecc...)
I used mutable collection for this reason, but in my map "a" is not possible insert element (side effects) but this update is only in return type, e not in a.
Why? how can I insert new element (x -> y) in my map a??

```
def a = scala.collection.mutable.map[Int,Int]()

def x = 5
def y = 6

a+= (x -> y)

println(a.size) // print 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you've defined `a` as a `def`, meaning a method. This means that each time you call `a`, a new instance of your mutable map is returned. What you want is a `val`:

```
@ val a = mutable.Map[Int, Int]()
a: mutable.Map[Int, Int] = Map()

@ a += (5 -> 6)
res2: mutable.Map[Int, Int] = Map(5 -> 6)
```